# Build webpages using Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, as in I was just given a task a few minutes ago and it's the first time I've ever looked at Python. Basically, I have an index.html file, and a header and footer file, and then some other webpage files. I am trying to use Python to insert the selects webpage into the index.html page when loaded, with the header and footer already there. This is the code I received with some pseudo code shown with the #.

```
#load main index.html
#mainHtml = 
#mainHtml.replace('<!--HEADER_CONTENT-->', headerHtml)
#mainHtml.replace('<!--FOOTER_CONTENT-->', footerHtml)



copy_tree(srcLoc, buildLoc)
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk(buildLoc):
  for fname in files:
    fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
    #todo only use html
    print(fpath)
    if '.html' in fpath:
      print('html')
      #create whole html page
      #thisPageHtml = 
      #minify
      #mainHtml_tmp is new mainHtml
      #mainHtml_tmp.replace('<!--PAGE_CONTENT-->', thisPageHtml)
      #write mainHtml_tmp to fpath
    if '.scss' in fpath:
      print('html')
      #compile to css & minify

    if '.js' in fpath:
      print('js')
      #minify
```

I was wondering if anyone could offer some help, guide me in the right direction, explain to me how to do this? Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough and I'll try to explain myself better.

Comment: Have you looked into writing a python cgi? https://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts

Comment: Instead of rolling your own templating system there are a multitude out there that already exist. Have a look at [some examples](https://www.fullstackpython.com/static-site-generator.html) and see if any fit your needs. This question is likely to get closed not because it's a bad question, but because it's highly subjective, there's no right answer. This choice is entirely personal and based on your particular requirements. Stack Overflow tries to stay focused on pragmatic programming problems that have specific, concrete answers.

Comment: @RedCricket That's a really creaky, old way of doing things. Django and Pylons/Pyramid use fCGI model.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this type of question.

Comment: @tadman The poster is a beginner. So no need to throw her in the deep end.

Comment: @RedCricket No need to throw someone back into the 1990s either. We have new tools and they're way better than the junk we had to suffer with back then. Don't think using current techniques or modern frameworks is somehow cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant bit for opening up a file, assuming you know its path, and reading and writing the data

```
with open(FILE_PATH, 'r') as f:
    file_html = f.read()

mainHtml = mainHtml.replace('<!--FOOTER_CONTENT-->', file_html)

with open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(mainHTML)
```

You'll want to use the `with open` style instead of opening and closing a file manually. The open with handle closing the file once you leave the `open` block.

Also split code up into functions. having a single long script isn't going to benefit you for very long. For example to open a file and replace some text in a given string.

```
def open_and_replace(file_path, pattern_to_replace, string_to_format):
    # open the file and read data into a variable called `data`
    return string_to_format.replace(pattern_to_replace, data)
```

Also note that there are various templating libraries out there, https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating if you feel you could benefit from them

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot. I was feeling overwhelmed with all the information I was coming across, and was very confused as to which path to take. Thank you for giving me a start and knowing which direction to continue on.